# how can i send email to multiple email addresses from sql

Tags: sql-server, email

I have a select query in sql.

I want to send email to all email addresses, if query gives 5 user send to 5 user or gives 85 user send to 85 users.
I have msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail but i didnt know how can i reach to all rows and send them the email.

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach to create a delimited list in SQL Server is the horribly arcane `STUFF subquery FOR XML PATH` method.  Assuming a table named `Contacts` holds the email addresses in a field named `email`:

```
DECLARE @Recipients nvarchar(max);

SELECT @Recipients = STUFF((SELECT ';' + email FROM Contacts FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```

The `@Recipients` variable should end up with a semicolon delimited list of email addresses, which [appears to be what `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` wants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql), but you might need to use a comma instead.